# How do I insert all the elements in a Python list into individual rows of an SQLAlchemy column?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi, pydantic

Trying to insert the elements of `exp_data` into individual rows of SQLAlchemy column `exp_list` inside the `Expiration` table programmatically using Python within the FastAPI framework:

```
exp_data = ['2020-08-27', '2020-09-03', '2020-09-10', '2020-09-17']
for i in exp_data:
   exp = Expiration(symbol=stock.symbol, exp_list=exp_data)

db.add_all([stock, exp])
db.commit()
```

And my SQLAlchemy model is:

```
from sqlalchemy import Boolean, Column, ForeignKey, Numeric, Integer, String, Date, Float
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, backref

from database import Base

class Stock(Base):
    __tablename__ = "stocks"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    symbol = Column(String)
    price = Column(Float)

class Expiration(Base):
    __tablename__ = "expirations"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    symbol = Column(String, ForeignKey(Stock.symbol), index=True)
    exp_list = Column(String)
```

I put `exp_data` in the code to show the size - I am scraping this data, and I want the program to automatically insert the data into the database by simply posting an HTTP Request of the stock ticker to the server. Been receiving this error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InterfaceError: (sqlite3.InterfaceError) Error binding parameter 1 - probably unsupported type.
[SQL: INSERT INTO expirations (symbol, exp_list) VALUES (?, ?)]
[parameters: ('FB', ['2020-08-27', '2020-09-03', '2020-09-10', '2020-09-17'])]
```

I think the issue is with the `for` loop in the first code block - I have been trying to find strategies to iterate through each value, such as `'2020-08-27'`, and insert it into individual rows. Any help is much appreciated - thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like

```
exp_data = ['2020-08-27', '2020-09-03', '2020-09-10', '2020-09-17']
exps = []
for date in exp_data:
   exps.append(Expiration(symbol=stock.symbol, exp_list=date))

instances = [stock]
instances.extend(exps)

db.add_all(instances)
db.commit()
```

that is, looping over the list of dates and creating an `Expiration` instance for each.

Comment: Okay that gave me something different. Got the error: `sqlalchemy.orm.exc.UnmappedInstanceError: Class 'builtins.list' is not mapped`, so I assume that the values within the list are not strings like I had thought when I made the `model`. Any suggestions? Appreciate your help!

Comment: I think `add_all` doesn't like a list within a list - try the edited answer.

Comment: You're the best. Can't thank you enough for the help.

Comment: It can also throw this error on the db.refresh(list)

Answer (score 0):

Your column :exp_list defined as string/text column

> **exp_list** = Column(String)

And then you pass a python list to it

> `exp_data` = ['2020-08-27', '2020-09-03', '2020-09-10', '2020-09-17'] 
> exp = Expiration(symbol=stock.symbol, **exp_list**=`exp_data`)

You should pass the list as string

```
exp = Expiration(symbol=stock.symbol, exp_list=','.join(exp_data))
```